# Unsubscribe/Resubscribe links are not working in salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, inline-visualforce, subscriber

Marketing Cloud Unsubscribe/Resubscribe links which are part of the marketing cloud managed package is not working in the salesforce contact page. We know these link will unsubscribe in Marketing cloud thru connectors and updates "email opt out" field. But today when we click those links then we got pop up error:

**Oops! This type of link is no longer supported to run within Salesforce DOM. Add the ContactActions inline Visualforce page to the page layout instead. Please contact your administrator to make this change**

I have checked for other buttons or actions if MC introduced for this functionality but none shows up, Error clearly says ContactActions inline VF page, I have looked into it but no use

Anyone experienced this issue, if yes please do let us know what is the solution for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue with the recent Winter 19 release and resolved it by replacing the MC components.

First remove the Marketing Cloud *custom links* on Contact, Lead and Campaign object layouts in Sales Cloud.

Then on the layouts add the Visualforce Pages ***AccountActions*** (depends per object) and drag to the place in the page layout.

Example from Campaign object:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error is related depending on the SFMC Connector version.

For v5 [most recent] the only way possible is via Leads or Contact Actions
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_update_page_layouts.htm&type=5

For v2, you can only use them in the classic version.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_si_resubscribing_contacts_and_leads.htm&type=5