# Marketing Cloud Connect Re-subscribe link in Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We are implementing the Marketing Cloud Resubscribe link in Sales Cloud and I have a few questions about it:

1. When we try to add it to the page layout, it says:

> Oops! This type of link is no longer supported to run within
>   Salesforce DOM. Add the ContactActions inline Visualforce page to the
>   page layout instead. Please contact your administrator to make this
>   change

Is there a replacement for this functionality available?

2. What we are able to install, is a set of three links, as displayed in below screenshot - is it possible to only include one of them, not all three? If yes - how?

[image]

3. What do those two links do exactly: "Send Marketing Cloud Email" and "View Marketing Cloud Analytics"?

Answer (score 0):

[Unsubscribe/Resubscribe links are not working in salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/238535/unsubscribe-resubscribe-links-are-not-working-in-salesforce)

SF Documentation:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_update_page_layouts.htm&type=5

For your Question 3:
The Send Marketing Cloud Email will send an email directly to the Contact or Lead being targeted without having to make a report or DE for sending.  This will show as Email Sends on the Contact Record and will not show a report or campaign as the audience.

Click on the View Analytics to see where it goes!