# Tracking From Marketing Cloud to Salesforce stopped working

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

tracking flow between Marketing Cloud and Salesforce has stopped working for our SF org since December 2019. I do not know what caused it; we currently have a case raised with support but doesn't seem to be getting anywhere.

The Email Sends are created but the tracking appears as in the print screen attached:

[image]

When I requested tracking I got the message: ''Oops! This type of button is no longer supported to run within Salesforce DOM. Add the EmailSendActions inline Visualforce page to the page layout instead. Please contact your administrator to make this change.''

I had one of our SF admins perform the steps as indicated in this post:

[Unsubscribe/Resubscribe links are not working in salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/238535/unsubscribe-resubscribe-links-are-not-working-in-salesforce)

Situation we are at the moment is that when I request tracing manually via this VF button it works but the automatic flow of tracking is broken; meaning i get the same ''waiting on tracking from Marketing Cloud'' message as in the print screen for all the sends definitions created via the sends from Marketing Cloud.

We have connected app installed with the recommended settings; our connector is at the latest level 222.1. Worth mentioning that we didn't have TSE enabled on the connector; I have enabled it early this week but didn't seem to have solved the issue.

Any guidance would be appreciated. What should I check to fix this and what is the cause for this? Support wasn't able to provide an answer for this.

Giulietta

Answer (score 1):

issue was related to a security that Marketing Cloud deployed to the connector 222.1 on December 14th 2019 that caused this. On 20th Jan they deployed a change that ensured the tracking was flowing automatically between MC and SF